# Input field with two entries-one on the left and one on the right

Tags: html, css

So basically i need an input field with the place holder "Name" on the left side, and placeholder "Michael" on the other(right) side of the input field.
So when the user starts typing in the text field, text will start form the right but the placeholder "Name" should be fixed and always stay on the screen.

Example:

```
[Name:------------------Michael]
[Last name:--------------Dawson]
[City:-----------------New York]
```

So 'Michael', 'Dawson' and 'New York' are user provided information(user type them).

So before user starts to type form looks like this:

```
[Name:-------------------------]
[Last name:--------------------]
[City:-------------------------]
```

And when user starts to type his input starts from the right.

```
[Name:-----------------------Mi]
[Name:---------------------Mich]
[Name:------------------Michael]
```

Can this be done with pure html/css?

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/7hv76swy/

Comment: This is not possible. You need to use a label (with NAME in it) in front of your input field (with placeholder MICHAEL)

Comment: Can you post your tried code?

Comment: @ManojKumar https://jsfiddle.net/7hv76swy/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
input {
    direction: rtl;
    padding-left:45px;
}
div {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:2px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Name:</span><input/></div>
```

Comment: This causes the cursor/carat to be placed incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexW Tnx, this is the best solution yet. I think it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input's placeholder attribute and style it differently from the entered text:

```css
input {
    text-align: right;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: left;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    text-align: left;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-align: left;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name:">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Therefore we need **two** `<input>` tags. One at the **left** and one at the **right**. The one at the **left** has the **attribute readonly** so no one can make an input. The one at the **right** is for **input** **only**. With `style="direction: rtl"`. Put those two together. The left has no border at the right side. The right has no border at the left side. Give both `<input>` tags the same border. The right `<input>` has a `margin-left: -(2 * border-width)px`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Amwiom/feadbrpu/)